matplotlib pyplot creates a broken plot when long
I'm struggling with this strange behavior in the matplotlib pyplot library.
The actual plot is more complex but I've reduced it to these few lines of python code:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot(w, h):

    num_samples = int(w * h)
    x = w * np.random.rand(num_samples)
    y = h * np.random.rand(num_samples)
    plt.figure(figsize=(w, h))
    plt.xticks(range(w))
    plt.xlim(0, w)
    plt.ylim(0, h)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.grid()


It basically creates a scatter plot given width and height parameters.
If I invoke this function like plot(5, 3), it will produce this figure:

I can use the function with greater width values, generating long plots like plot(100, 3):

But if I use it with a greater width it creates a "broken plot" plot(450, 3):

Note that

the lines of the containing frame are kind of dashed?
there are scatter dots outside the containing frame.


why?
Is it a bug in the library?

This might be a bug that should be reported through the GitHub issues page.

Before reporting, verify this is an issue on the newest version of the library.

Ok! I've tested the same code in google colab and the problem is present. So if colab has the last version of the library I think it is not related to the version.

thanks @jared for your advice, I've just added the issue to the official library repository.
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/28137

Depending on the backend used to run matplotlib, plt.figure(figsize=(450, 3)) would be much too large, especially when running in interactive mode. See e.g. Setting figure size to be larger than screen size in matplotlib. In this post, one of matplotlib maintainers mentions a maximum figsize of 50 inches.

It seems it is a known bug, reported in 2023. Related to the AGG function that matplotlib uses as is mentioned here. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26368
